# Vertical and horizontal spacing in a two-line equation

Tags: spacing, equations

I wrote the following:

```
\begin{equation} 
\begin{array}{lcl}
w_{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} & = & m(\dfrac{n-2}{1+\varepsilon_1})(m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho}){{n-2} \choose {\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}} ^{-1} \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1+ \varepsilon_i)\\
& = & (1+o(1))n \cdot m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho-1}{{n-2} \choose {\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}} ^{-1} \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1+ \varepsilon_i)\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The output is as attached.

1. How can I make the binomial part look "taller" or nicer?
2. How can I make the spacing between lines are more as it looks very messy and cramp?
3. How can I make the writings on top and bottom of the `\prod` sign instead of beside it?
4. Anyhow can make it nicer?

Thank you.

Comment: By my count, the term `\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho` occurs 7 times in the two lines. Are you open to setting, say, `M=\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho` and then using `M` wherever applicable? For sure, the equations will look a lot simpler...

Answer (score 4):

Package `amsmath` provides lots of macros and environments for mathematical typesetting. Environment `align` can be used instead of an additional `array` for aligning (with `\nonumber` one of the equation numbers can be suppressed if necessary). Alternatively, environment `aligned` can be used inside `equation`.
With the proper environments, the math is set in `\displaystyle`, generating a larger binomial expression and the limits above and below the `\prod` symbol.

Macro `\binom` makes it easier to set the binomial expression. Also I have applied a small spacing correction for the superscript after the closing parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  w_{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}
  & =
  m(\dfrac{n-2}{1+\varepsilon_1})(m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho})
  \binom{n-2}{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}^{\!-1}
  \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1+\varepsilon_i)\\
  & =
  (1+o(1))n \cdot m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho-1}
  \binom{n-2}{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}^{\!-1}
  \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1+\varepsilon_i)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest you make the following changes:

- Instead of an `array` environment, use an `align` environment. Increase the vertical separation between the rows a bit.
- Don't use the `{{... \choose ...}}` "Plain-TeX" syntax. Instead, use the `amsmath` macro `\binom{...}{...}`.
- Reduce the space between the binomial term and the following `{-1}` exponent, and widen the space between the `{-1}` exponent and the following product symbol.
- Use `\smashoperator` directives to snug up the `(1+ \varepsilon_i)` terms to the product symbols.
- To emphasize that some "items" are in sub- or superscript positions, insert a `\mathstrut` in the corresponding super- and subscript positions. The result will be that it's more obvious what's sub- and superscript material. This affects the subscript to `w` and the superscripts to `m`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
w_{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}^{\mathstrut}
&= m\biggl(\frac{n-2}{1+\varepsilon_1}\biggr)
m_{\mathstrut}^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho}
\binom{n-2}{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} ^{\!-1} \,
\smashoperator[r]{\prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}} (1+ \varepsilon_i)  
  \notag\\[2ex]  % only one equation number for the entire expression
&= \bigl(1+o(1)\bigr)n \cdot 
m_{\mathstrut}^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho-1}
\binom{n-2}{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} ^{\!-1} \,
\smashoperator[r]{\prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}} (1+ \varepsilon_i)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: By my count, the unwieldy-looking term `\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho` occurs seven [7!] times in this two-row expression. You may want to define, say, `M=\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho$` and then generate the following, (IMNSHO) much more pleasant looking formula:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align" environment and "\binom" macro

\begin{document}
Set $M=\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho$. Then
\begin{align}
w_{M}^{}
&= m \frac{n-2}{1+\varepsilon_1}
m^{-M}
\binom{n-2}{M} ^{\!\!-1} 
\prod_{i=1}^{M} (1+ \varepsilon_i)  
  \notag\\  % only one equation number for the entire expression
&= \bigl(1+o(1)\bigr)n m^{-M+1}
\binom{n-2}{M} ^{\!\!-1} 
\prod_{i=1}^{M} (1+ \varepsilon_i)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You actually do not use the functions provided by `array`, so I'd suggest you use `align*` from the `amsmath` package.

I use `\\[<dimension>]` to add some space to a line break, e.g. `\\[5pt]`.

Use `\binom{a}{b}` instead of `a choose b`.

And use `\left( ... \right)` to have parentheses adapt automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
w_{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} & = m\left(\frac{n-2}{1+\varepsilon_1}\right)\left(m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho}\right)\binom{n-2}{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}^{-1} \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1+ \varepsilon_i)\\[\medskipamount]
 &= (1+o(1))n \cdot m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho-1}\binom{n-2}{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}^{-1} \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1+ \varepsilon_i)
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
w_{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} & = 
    m\left(\dfrac{n-2}{1+\varepsilon_1}\right)
    m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho}
    {{n-2}\choose{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}}^{-1} 
    \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1 + \varepsilon_i)   \\
                        & = 
    (1+o(1))n m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho-1}
    {{n-2}\choose{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}}^{-1} 
    \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1 + \varepsilon_i)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Math environment `split` preserve `choose` in display style. Or alternatively, as asked in the comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
XXXX
\begin{align}
w_{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} & = 
    m\left(\dfrac{n-2}{1+\varepsilon_1}\right)
    m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho}
    \binom{n-2}{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}^{-1} 
    \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1 + \varepsilon_i)   
                        \notag  \\
                        & = 
    (1+o(1))n m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho-1}{{n-2} 
    \choose{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}}^{-1} 
    \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho} (1 + \varepsilon_i)
\end{align}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Zarko. What if I want the equation sign (1) on the last line instead of the middle?

Comment: Then instead `begin{equation}\begin{split}` use just `\begin{align}`, ended with `end{align}`, the same as show Heiko aOberdiek and end first line width `\notag \\`.

Answer (score 1):

As the `\binom`or `dbinom` commands from `amsmath` have a fixed size which may not be enough (this is the case here if the fraction inside \binom is set in displaystyle), I use the `DeclarePairedDelimiterX` command, from `mathtools`  to define a `\Binom` command, with a star version that adds a pair of implicit `\left … \right` around the parentheses. You also may fine-tune their size with an optional argument (`\big, \Big, \bigg,\Bigg`).

Furthermore, we can use, inside the binomial, a `\dfrac` command or an `\mfrac` command (these are `medium-sized` fraction, ~80% of \displaystyle) from the `nccmath` package. Also, I  neutralised the width of the upper bound of the indices and agjusted the whole formula with some `math kerning` (for your information, the unit length for maths is `mu=1/18 em`; `\,=3mu`). Finally, I thought it would be better to have only one number for both lines, but that is easy to change.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Binom[2](){\mkern-1mu\begin{matrix}#1\\#2\end{matrix}\mkern-1mu}%{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
  \begin{aligned}
    w_{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}
      & =
    m\cdot\dfrac{n-2}{1+\varepsilon_1}\cdot m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho}
    \Binom*{n-2}{\mfrac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}^{\mkern-6mu-1}\mkern12mu
    \prod_{i=1}^{\mathclap{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}} (1+\varepsilon_i)\\[1ex]
      & =
    \bigl (1+o(1)\bigr)n \cdot m^{-\frac{mn}{m+1}+\rho-1}
    \Binom*{n-2}{\cfrac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}^{\mkern-9mu -1}\mkern12mu
    \prod_{i=1}^{\mathclap{\frac{mn}{m+1}-\rho}} (1+\varepsilon_i)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clear now. :-)